# Count if date in date column is between start and end date [ Oracle SQL ]

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count

This is my first post, so I hope I've posted this one correctly.

#### My problem:

I want to count the number of active customers per day, the last 30 days.

#### What I have so far:

In the first column I want to print today, and the last 29 days. This I have done with

```
select distinct trunc(sysdate-dayincrement, 'DD') AS DATES
from   (
  select level as dayincrement
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 30
)
```

I've picked it up here at stackoverflow, and it works perfectly. I can even extend the number of days returned to ex. 365 days. Perfect!

I also have a table that looks like this

```
|Cust# | Start date | End date  |
| 1000 | 01.01.2015 | 31.12.2015|
| 1001 | 02.01.2015 | 31.12.2016|
| 1002 | 02.01.2015 | 31.03.2015|
| 1003 | 03.01.2015 | 31.08.2015|
```

**This is where I feel the problem starts**

I would like to get this result:

```
| Dates    | # of cust |
|04.01.2015|     4     |
|03.01.2015|     4     |
|02.01.2015|     3     |
|01.01.2015|     1     |
```

Here the query would count 1 if:

- Start date <= DATES
- End date >= DATES

Else count 0.

I just don't know how to structure the query.

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
count(
  IF ENDDATE <= DATES THEN
    IF STARTDATE >= DATES THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IF
  ELSE
    0
  END IF
) AS CUST
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to SUM the COUNT of dates and GROUP BY the dates. Not by my PC otherwise I would write a proper answer for you.

Comment: Thank you for help! :) I'm think you're right about SUM, and of course about the GROUP BY as well. However, I get an error message. ORA-00923 (misplaced FROM). I think this one comes from the customer table being a "mixed table" I have created from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following produces the results you're looking for. I had change the date generator to start on 04-JAN-**2015** instead of SYSDATE (which is, of course, in the year **2016**), and to use `LEVEL-1` to include 'current' day:

```
WITH CUSTS AS (SELECT 1000 AS CUST_NO, TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS START_DATE, TO_DATE('31-DEC-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS END_DATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 1001 AS CUST_NO, TO_DATE('02-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS START_DATE, TO_DATE('31-DEC-2016', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS END_DATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 1002 AS CUST_NO, TO_DATE('02-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS START_DATE, TO_DATE('31-MAR-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS END_DATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 1003 AS CUST_NO, TO_DATE('03-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS START_DATE, TO_DATE('31-AUG-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS END_DATE FROM DUAL ),
     DATES AS (SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(TO_DATE('04-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') - DAYINCREMENT, 'DD') AS DT
                FROM (SELECT LEVEL-1 AS DAYINCREMENT
                        FROM DUAL
                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30))
SELECT d.DT, COUNT(*)
  FROM CUSTS c
  CROSS JOIN DATES d
  WHERE d.DT BETWEEN c.START_DATE AND c.END_DATE
  GROUP BY d.DT
  ORDER BY DT DESC
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Oh. Damn.
That one worked! :D

Thank you VERY much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a **CASE** expression equivalent to your **IF-ELSE** construct.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT COUNT(
  2    CASE
  3      WHEN hiredate <= sysdate
  4      THEN 1
  5      ELSE 0
  6    END ) AS CUST
  7  FROM emp;

      CUST
----------
        14

SQL>
```

However, looking at your desired output, it seems, you just need to use **COUNT** and **GROUP BY**. The **date conditions** should be in the **filter predicate**.

For example,

```
SELECT dates, COUNT(*) 
FROM   table_name
WHERE  dates BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
GROUP BY dates;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! :)
However, this does not keep the dates in the left column?
I need this because I would like to get a time series to later be used for graphing of number of customers.

Comment: @PKH That was a small typo. Just put `dates` in the select.